# C++ C# delegate Equivalent

Tags: c#, c++

I will attempt to keep this question as succinct as possible.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Something {
    static class Program {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            int blah = DoSomethingWithThis( delegate {
                Console.WriteLine( "Hello World" );
            } );
        }

        public static int DoSomethingWithThis( Action del ) {
            del.Invoke(); // Prints Hello World to the console
            int someArbitraryNumber = 31;
            return someArbitraryNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

In C# I can use an anonymous method as a parameter to do something like this;
I was wondering if anyone can show me the same thing in C++, or something very similar that would facilitate the same outcome. I plan on using something like the above code to create a DisplayList generator for my game in C++.

Comment: Read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = { "Hello ", "Wordl" };

    std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), 
                   []( const std::string &s) { std::cout << s; } )( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Hello Wordl
```

So you can write yourself some function that accepts as an argument a functional object (or an object of type std::function) and then pass a lambda expression as the argument.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

int DoSomethingWithThis( std::function<void( void )> del )
{
    del();

    int someArbitraryNumber = 31;
    return someArbitraryNumber;
}


int main() 
{
    int blah = DoSomethingWithThis( [] { std::cout << "Hello World"; } );

    std::cout << "\nblah = " << blah << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Hello World
blah = 31
```

In C# you also can substitute an anonymous method for a lambda expression.

Comment: And I knew about lambdas, I just wanted something short and concise like a delegate declaration.